# how to let format string work in correct way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
    class Fahrzeug:
def __init__(self,Leergewicht,Baujahr):
    self.Leergewicht = Leergewicht
    self.Baujahr
def __str__(self):
    v =  "Leergewciht : {} Baujahr {}"
    return v.format(str(self.Leergewicht),str(self.Baujahr))
```

rad = Fahrzeug(10, 2019, 55)
print(rad)

**it raises an error :
File "Bl12.py", line 6
return "Leergewciht : {} Baujahr {}".
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
**

Comment: Please correct your indentation

Comment: The line in the error message doesn't appear in the code you've shown. You aren't running what you think you're running.

Comment: Please make sure that the code pasted here reflects *exactly* what is in your source file, including all indentation. Copy and paste the *entire* block of code, then re-select the entire code and press the `{}` button to format it. Use the same formatting for the error message as it appears in the console.

Comment: It's most likely formatting. Did you mix up tabs and spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget assign value in init self.Baujahr = Baujahr

```
class Fahrzeug:
    def __init__(self,Leergewicht, Baujahr):
        self.Leergewicht = Leergewicht
        self.Baujahr = Baujahr

    def __str__(self):
        v =  "Leergewciht : {} Baujahr {}"
        return v.format(str(self.Leergewicht),str(self.Baujahr))


x = Fahrzeug('Leergewicht', 'Baujahr')
print(x)
```